# Figuring out the span of 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

So I'm given that: $$A := \{(\alpha,\alpha,\alpha) :\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ and $$B := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x+y+z=0\}.$$

I've determined that:

1. $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since a) the $0$-vector is in the vector space, b) it holds under addition c) holds under a scalar multiple.
2. $B$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since a) the $0$-vector is in the vector space, b) it holds under addition: $$(1,-2, 1) + (2, -2, 0) = (3, -4, 1)$$ and that vector holds, so it holds. Multiplication: $$ cx + cy + cz = 0 \Rightarrow c(x+y+z) = 0,$$ so it holds under a scalar multiplication.
3. $A \bigcap B = \{0\}$ since the only vector that is shared in common is when $x=y=z=0$.

So, now I am wondering: how to go about this question?

Comment: Hint: $B$ is two dimensional so any two LI vectors in $B$ will span $B$.

Comment: How would I find this? I'm not too sure. Also just checking, my statements 1) and 2) and 3) are correct, right? I feel like it may be helpful information @KaviRamaMurthy